# Wikipedia MediaWiki API Get Template Content via URL Request

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I've been going through the doc's for past few hours and simply can't seem to figure this out though probably simple.

I have this link:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=expandtemplates&titles=Arabinose&text={{Chembox%20Elements}}&prop=wikitext
```

Which obviously will give me the schema of Template Chembox | Chembox Elements in this case.

All I simply want is to retrieve the Molecular forumla content/data/value for the given page/title without having to parse the entire wiki content at my end.

Understand I have prop=wikitext which will be returning wikitext in the above example, there's no option in expandtemplates for prop=text. I've been back and forth with action=query, expandedtemplates etc and no joy.

Comment: I think you will have to parse it yourself. The templates are not structured data (even if they look structured) so the API does not know anything about its content.

Comment: WikiData have some structured data for chemicals, like here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q407373

The formula property is called `P274`, so you want to ask the API for property `P274` of item `Q407373`, to get `C₅H₁₀O₅'

Comment: Obviously give you the schema? Not at all. See leo.

Answer (score 1):

MediaWiki's API won't do the work for you. You'll have to parse your own results.